# Не могу определить откуда подгружаются данные

Tags: парсер

На сайте olx.kz, там есть div (.categorySelectContainer) со списком ul(.categorySelectList), где есть все города, при get запросе это поле пустое, после клика оно подгружается

Все ответы которые я нашел, это посмотреть ajax запросы и куда они идут, либо как плохой вариант использовать selenium

Я смотрел запросы, но не нашел то что надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Области хранятся в переменной `geotop`, она доступна в глобальной области видимости и уже существует на странице без выполнения каких либо ajax запросов. За формирование списка `li` отвечает функция `function initCitiesHtml($proposalContainer, settings)`, которая создает разметку и вставляет ее в код страницы. Событие, вызывающее вставку областей - `click` на `input#cityField`. Конкретное место регистрации события не нашел.